# 標準ライブラリ（ctype.h）のコンパイルエラーについて

Tags: linux, c++, ubuntu, gcc

ardupilotというオープンソースのソースを改変しながら開発を進めています。
最近g++でビルドした際に標準ライブラリ内でエラーが発生するようになりました。エラー内容は以下の通りです（環境はubuntudです）。

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_ios.h:37:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:44,
             from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
             from ../../libraries/AP_IRLock/AP_IRLock_SITL.cpp:30:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_facets.h:2601:44: error: macro "isdigit" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
 isdigit(_CharT __c, const locale& __loc)
                                        ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

内容から察するにlocale_facets.hでしようされているisdigit関数の引数が２つ指定されているが、ctype.h内のisdigit関数の引数は１つしか要求していないということだと思います。
事実、/usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_facets.h内のisidigitと/usr/include/ctype.h内のisdigitが異なっていることは確認できています。
g++のバージョンを4.7に変更したりしましたが、ダメでした。
ちなみに今のg++のバージョンは5.4.1です。
g++,gccの際インストール等も行いましたが、結果はダメでした。

どなたか助けてください。

Answer (score 3):

記述されているのはC++のソースかと思いますが、`/usr/include/ctype.h`はC向けのヘッダファイルなので食い違いが起きています。
include行を見直してもらい、`#include <locale>`で定義されている`std::isdigit`の方を呼び出せば引数を2つ取るisdigitが利用できるようです。

[ctype.h の isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/)
[std::locale の isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/isdigit/)

**std::isdigit を利用したコードサンプル**

```
// isdigit example (C++)
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <string>         // std::string
#include <locale>         // std::locale, std::isdigit
#include <sstream>        // std::stringstream

int main ()
{
  std::locale loc;
  std::string str="1776ad";
  if (isdigit(str[0],loc))
  {
    int year;
    std::stringstream(str) >> year;
    std::cout << "The year that followed " << year << " was " << (year+1) << ".\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**参考：**
英語版SOでの関連質問
[c++ - isspace macro conflicting with isspace function in locale_facets.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059308/isspace-macro-conflicting-with-isspace-function-in-locale-facets-h)

Answer (score 3):

あなたがソース改変する際に、今まで無かった `#include <ctype.h>` を追加したのだと思います。これは [c](/questions/tagged/c) ヘッダなので [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ヘッダの `#include <locale>` と喧嘩してしまいます (`#define` で `std::isdigit` を隠蔽してしまうなど)

既存コードが使っているなどの理由により、２引数の `std::isdigit` ではなくて１引数の `isdigit` を使う必要があるのなら `#include <ctype.h>` ではなくて `#include <cctype>` とするとよいでしょう。

あるいは１引数の `isdigit` を廃して２引数の `std::isdigit` に統一する、でしょうか。その場合必要なのは `#include <locale>` だけなので `#include <ctype.h>` あるいは `#include <cctype>` は削除となります。